# How to pass single Socket IO Instance to pages with Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

So I'm trying to use one single Socket IO instance in my entire App and access it from multiple components.

I searched a lot already and tried a lot too... without any success.

Right now Im using the React Context API.

Im initialising my `SocketContext` in `SocketProvider.js`:

```
import React from 'react'

const SocketContext = React.createContext()

export default SocketContext
```

Opening the Socket and Providing it in `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import SocketContext from './services/SocketProvider'


function App() {
  const socket = io("http://localhost:8000")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        <MuiThemeProvider >
          <Main />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </SocketContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Routing in `Main.js`:

```
function Main() {

  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Menu} />

        <Route path="/panorama" component={Panorama} />
        <Route path="/movie" component={Movie} />

        <Route
          path="/timelapse"
          render={({ match: { url } }) => (
            <>
              <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Timelapse} exact />
              <Route path={`${url}/running`} render={(props) => <Running {...props} type={'timelapse'} />} />

            </>
          )}
        />

      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}


export default Main;
```

And using it in those two Components, `Timelapse.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import SocketContext from '../../services/SocketProvider';
import TimelapsePoints from '../../components/TimelapsePoints/TimelapsePoints';
import TimelapseCamControls from '../../components/TimelapseCamControls/TimelapseCamControls'


class Timelapse extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let socket = props.socket;

        this.state = {
            hasCamera: false,
            cameraActive: false,
            brightnessControl: false,
            camControlsOk: false,
            pointsOk: false,
            interval: 10,
            recordingTime: 6000,
            movieTime: 12
        };

        socket.on('hasCamera', data => {
            this.setState({
                cameraActive: data.hasCamera
            })
            this.setState({
                hasCamera: data.hasCamera
            })
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (<div >
            {
                this.state.cameraActive &&
                <TimelapseCamControls brightnessControl={
                        this.state.brightnessControl
                    }
                    toggleBrightnesscontrol={
                        this.toggleBrightnesscontrol
                    }
                    camControlsOk={
                        this.camControlsOk
                    }
                    socket={
                        this.props.socket
                    }
                />
            } {
                (!this.state.brightnessControl || (this.state.brightnessControl && this.state.camControlsOk)) &&


        <TimelapsePoints socket={this.props.socket} handlePointsChange={this.pointsOk}/>

                {this.state.pointsOk && this.camControlsOk &&
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.timelapse} href="/timelapse/running">
                Start
              </Button>
                }
                </div>
        );
    }
}

const TimelapseWithSocket = (props) => (
    <SocketContext.Consumer>
      {socket => <Timelapse {...props} socket={socket} />}
    </SocketContext.Consumer>
)
export default TimelapseWithSocket;
```

and `Running.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import SocketContext from '../../services/SocketProvider';

class Running extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            progress: 0,
            maxProgress: 100,
            waypoints: []
        };

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.socket.on('progress', data => {
            this.setState({
                progress: data.value,
                maxProgress: data.max
            })
        })

        this.props.socket.on('timelapseInfo', data => {
            console.log('recived date');
            this.setState({
                waypoints: data.waypoints,
                maxProgress: data.max
            })
        })

        console.log("component mounte");
    }



    render() {
        var type = this.props.type;
        var title = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)

        return (<div >

        </div>
        );
    }
}

const RunningWithSocket = (props) => (
    <SocketContext.Consumer>
      {socket => <Running {...props} socket={socket} />}
    </SocketContext.Consumer>
)

export default RunningWithSocket;
```

But as soon as I hit the route `/timelapse/running` I get a new Socket Instance and I don't know why and how to fix it.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 7):

To achieve the same result you don't need the Context API but simply export the websocket connection from a module:

```
// ws.js
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const ws = io.connect(<host>)

export { ws }
```

Then you can use useEffect(fn, []) in your components to add events, the two square brackets as a second parameter are used to make the effect run only once:

```
// wsComponent.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { ws } from 'ws.js'

const WsComponent = () => {
  const [wsState, updateWsState] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    ws.on('connect', () => {
      updateWsState(true)
    })
    ws.on('disconnect', () => {
      updateWsState(false)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <Text>{wsState ? 'ONLINE' : 'OFFLINE'}</Text>
  )
}

export { WsComponent }
```

sorry if I made mistakes in the code, I didn't test it.

Comment: socket is null inside of useEffect and adding socket to dependency array of the same useEffect does not help...

Answer (score 0):

It may help to make your App component a pure component and/or extracting your socket provider into it's own pure component to avoid re-rendering, which might be causing the change in instance.  Alternatively, you can try wrapping your socket.io package in a singleton pattern.

Comment: There might be a problem with using `href` in `Timelapse.js` this might cause a reload of `App`?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in changing the Route with `href` on my Button insted of using the `Link` Component which will not trigger a complete reload of the App thus initialising a new Socket IO Instance.

So instead of using:

```
<Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.timelapse} href="/timelapse/running">Start</Button>
```

I had to use:

```
<Button variant="outlined" onClick={this.timelapse} component={ Link } to="/timelapse/running">Start</Button>
```

Hope this might serve as a solution for someone running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a socket.js where you export the client socket created by io(...)
const io = require('socket.io-client')
module.exports = io('http://localhost:5000') //your port


//when you need to use the socket just import and enjoy
import socket from './socket'
socket.on('some_event',()=>{ console.log('do something') })
```